# Is this sentence correct ? 我不知道会发我们的什么照片,所以就选择这个

Tags: writing-critique

你们好!

Hi, can you please tell me is this sentence correct?:

我不知道会发我们的什么照片,所以就选择[了]这个。 (I don't know to post which photo of us, so I chose this one).

谢谢 !

Comment: Do you mean that you chose a random one?

Comment: Yes, I mean I chose a random one.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know to post which photo of us, so I chose this one

"我不知道（应该）发我们的哪(一)张照片，所以我选(择)了这(一)张"

Use `应该` instead of `会` when the person can decide what to do himself/herself.
Use `张` instead of `个` when referring to paper stuff.
`which` means `哪一(个/张/..）` while `what` means `什么`.
`一` can be omitted in Chinese if no ambiguity.

Some examples:

I don't know what to do. 我不知道**应该**做什么.
I don't know what will happen. 我不知道**会**发生什么.
I don't know which to choose. 我不知道(应该)选哪一个.

一 **张** 纸/照片
一 **个** 东西/箱子

For accurate translation:
post: "发布", post online; "邮寄", post by mail

Comment: 非常感谢你的回答 ! 所以如果我说"我不知道应该(发布)哪一张照片也是对的吗 ?

Comment: @M.m  "我不知道应该发(布)哪一张照片" 是可以的。"发"不可以省略。

Comment: 明白了 ! 谢谢你的帮助 ~~